# Why Latin Modern Mono boldface series doesn't look like a bold?

Tags: fonts, bold, latin-modern, lmodern

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ttfamily\footnotesize % small size is set intentionally
Keywords are \textbf{\textsc{normal}}\\
Keywords are \textbf{\textsc{bold}}\\
Keywords are \textsc{caps}\\
Keywords are \textbf{\textsc{bold-and-caps}}\\
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I think no one in rush will find any reasonable difference between normal and **bold**. I did what has been said in https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/latinmodernmono to get the same result and also tried automagic package `bold-extra` which didn't any make difference either. Yes, I could have set `\fontseries{l}\selectfont` in order to make it even more obvious but I don't prefer using light for mono. So what do I wrong? Also you can see that smallcaps + bold do not mix but it feels like they might if only bold "start working".

---

Comparing with `\usepackage{sourcecodepro}`, it really makes that contrast:

[image]

Yes, it doesn't support smallcaps but it is expected as shown in aforementioned Font Catalogue.

Comment: well it is the font design. There is no bold extended, only a bold version. Already in the 10pt design size the difference between bold and normal is less pronounced than in sourcecodepro, and if you scale down the difference is scaled down too. The bold-extra package does nothing here, it is only for the cmtt/cmr fonts in OT1-encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `countor` package, for example, it could be a solution. You can change the parameter `1`, `2` for to have a strong bold.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{contour}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ttfamily\footnotesize % small size is set intentionally
Keywords are \textbf{\textsc{normal bold}}\\
Keywords are \textbf{\contour[2]{black}{\textsc{bold}}}\\
Keywords are \textsc{\contour[1]{black}{caps}}\\
Keywords are \contour[1]{black}{\textsc{bold-and-caps}}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First a couple of considerations:

- the `bold-extra` package does nothing when the font family is `lmtt`;
- there is no boldface small caps font in `lmtt`.

Indeed you get

```latex
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/lmtt/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/lmtt/bx/n' instead on input line 8.
```

A modified example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{bold-extra}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\ttfamily\footnotesize % small size is set intentionally
Keywords are \textbf{\textsc{normal \fontname\font}}\\
Keywords are \textbf{\textsc{bold \fontname\font}}\\
Keywords are \textsc{caps \fontname\font}\\
Keywords are \textbf{\textsc{bold-and-caps \fontname\font}}\\

\end{document}
```

shows that the bold font is indeed used. The same would be with the OT1 encoding. The problem is that the boldface Latin Modern Typewriter font is not really as heavy as it would be necessary to have a really distinguishable look.

[image]

With the `lighttt` option you get distinct looks:

[image]

Solution? Use a different typewriter font.